# Creating a Vineyard Map with QGIS using Fishnet

Tags: qgis, map-drawing

In the vineyard there is a set number of rows, with a distance between each row and then the vines sit along the rows at the same distance apart.

I have tried using a Fishnet to map the rows and then the vines on the points of the fishnet. But having trouble moving that layer to sit inline with the GPS data I have for the four points that bound the vineyard.

I was wondering if there is any quick way to create the Rows and the Vines on the rows ? And then move the drawing into place with the GPS Data ?  As there is over 20,000 vines in the vineyard and each point will need to be drawn and the Fishnet and point is taking sometime.

For example, Block A - 2.7m per row, 1.25m between each vine with 80 rows in total and 300m long ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: Is this better tittle ?

Answer (score 2):

Using your example measurements I created a polygon of the whole area. If your using GPS coordinates you can create that using "Vector  >  Geoprocessing Tools  >  Convex Hull".

Then I created the fishnet using "Vector  >  Research Tools  >  Vector Grid", using the polygon previously created as the grid extent and the row space and vine space as the parameters.  Output as lines!  If you vineyard isn't perfectly straight you can add a rotation which will output the grid at an angle

[image]

You can see that they are whole lines and not separated from the intersections. Useful for your vine rows as each row now has an ID (important for later).

Now to create the vines.  That's done with "Vector  >  Analysis Tools  >  Line Intersection".  Use your grid and grid ID and run to create points at all grid intersections.

[image]

Each point now has it's own ID as well as the row ID, useful.
If you vineyards aren't exactly square just trim them down using "Vector  >  Geoprocessing Tools  >  Intersection"

Comment: Awesome, I'll play around with your tips and see how I go. But looks like this should make it more straight forward :)